# A Quadratic Diophantine equation in three variables

Tags: number-theory

Can the following Diophantine equation be solved for all solutions?

$$x^2 + yz = 2$$

Then get a closed expression for $x_n, y_n, z_n$.

It may be related to primes.
 I'll explain further how I got this.
If we've all the solutions for the above Diophantine equation it will yield all primes of the form n^2-2

derivation,

n^2-2=n^2-t^+t^2-2

(n-t)(n+t)+t^2-2
So n^2-2 is a composite iff there exist k integer t^2-r-2=k(n-t)
 ,of course n-t must not be 1

Since n-t>1 let n=t+1+z

thus t^2-r=k(1+z)

Now let k=Y, 1+z=Z and t=X then

X^2 + YZ = r where Z>1 and X, Y and Z are integers

if we can get a closed expression as it explained in http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0405/0405206.pdf
,we've got primes.

Comment: May need to write? $X^2-YZ=2$

Comment: Isn't this "easy" in the sense that $x$ can be arbitrary, and then $y$ can be any factor of $2-x^2$. Those two determine a unique $z$?

Comment: To put it another way, to find all solutions, you'd have top be able to factor every number of the form $x^2-2$, which is asking a bit much.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, My quest is to find  number of the form x^2−2 which does not have factors (primes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation:  $$X^2-YZ=2$$

Has a solution:  $$X=k(k+1)-2$$

$$Y=k^2-2$$

$$Z=k(k+2)-1$$

$$.....$$

$$X=(q^2-2)(k-1)k-(2k-1)q+1$$

$$Y=(q^2-2)(k-1)^2-2(k-1)q+1$$

$$Z=(q^2-2)k^2-2kq+1$$

$k,q$ - any integer.

Comment: Of course, this gives some solutions, but not all solutions. E.g., you don't get $X=3$, $Y=1$, $Z=7$.

Comment: It is an interesting parametric solution but I'm going to nees all the solution. http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0405/0405206.pdf

Comment: @dulshan I wrote all the decisions. Although you can write formulas in the equations, Pell.

Comment: @ individ, Thank you But I need a function which give consecutive X+Z . Can you help me with that,  Also can you mention some reference to how to find solutions as you mentioned above answer.

Comment: @dulshan I badly understand English. Consistent is it? Maybe it is better to make the difference? So it was clear rewrite it as an equation. For the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @individ, X+Z =f(n)  ; n=1,2,3...    X+Z in one variable. Can we do it.

Comment: @dulshan Take the formula and put. $X+Z$ or $X+Y$. One variable can be removed.  But why? What's the point? With primes it is not connected.